# Backfill timeseries in pandas with last available data point

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) which takes a snapshot every hour of every day.  Below is a partial output:

```
       date_time     score     distance
12/08/2021 21:00    1.7655   1538061.73
12/08/2021 22:00    1.7520   1531284.36
12/08/2021 23:00    1.7343   1595898.01
13/08/2021 00:00    1.8340   4117927.26
13/08/2021 01:00    1.8689  10397333.06
13/08/2021 02:00    1.8714   6825618.87
13/08/2021 07:00    1.9792   3842945.91
13/08/2021 08:00    1.9695   4876248.15
13/08/2021 09:00    2.0296   7668406.66
13/08/2021 10:00    2.0274   8542998.64
13/08/2021 11:00    2.0374   3705188.96
```

You can see that between `13/08/2021 02:00` and `13/08/2021 07:00` (i.e. `13/08/2021 03:00`, `13/08/2021 04:00`, `13/08/2021 05:00` and `13/08/2021 06:00`) data is missing.

Is there a way to systematically identify and gaps and backfill with the last previously available data point.  So the desired output in my example would be:

```
       date_time     score     distance
12/08/2021 21:00    1.7655   1538061.73
12/08/2021 22:00    1.7520   1531284.36
12/08/2021 23:00    1.7343   1595898.01
13/08/2021 00:00    1.8340   4117927.26
13/08/2021 01:00    1.8689  10397333.06
13/08/2021 02:00    1.8714   6825618.87
13/08/2021 03:00    1.8714   6825618.87
13/08/2021 04:00    1.8714   6825618.87
13/08/2021 05:00    1.8714   6825618.87
13/08/2021 06:00    1.8714   6825618.87
13/08/2021 07:00    1.9792   3842945.91
13/08/2021 08:00    1.9695   4876248.15
13/08/2021 09:00    2.0296   7668406.66
13/08/2021 10:00    2.0274   8542998.64
13/08/2021 11:00    2.0374   3705188.96
```

where the score and the distance from `13/08/2021 02:00` has been used to populate the missing data points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the index of the dataframe to use the timestamps, you can use pandas.resample() on your dataframe, setting it to generate a row every hour and forward-filling when null values are encountered...

```
df.set_index('date_time', drop=True, inplace=True)
df = df.resample('1H', fill_method='ffill')
```

[image]